# How to get segments that make up a general path?

Tags: java, vector

For a given character, font and size, I want to find the segments that make up the glyph.

```
    String text = "C";
    Font f = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);
    GlyphVector gv = f.createGlyphVector(frc, 
    GeneralPath gp = (GeneralPath) gv.getOutline();
```

So now I have a general path, but I want the linetos and curvetos that make this path. I can't seem to find a method that will get this, so I beleive I may be taking the wrong approach. What can I do here?

Comment: Why? What do you want to do with these segments? If we know what the requirement is (not your attempted solution) we might be able to offer a better approach.

Comment: My goal is to take a character and turn it into a dxf format consisting of lines/polylines (no curves). Thanks to camickr and ug_ for the help. I am back on my way

Answer (score 2):

The `getPathIterator()` method of `GeneralPath` will you these segments.

Answer (score 1):

See [PathIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html) which you can get from any [Shape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) object. Your `gv.getOutline()` returns a [Shape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html).

Heres a simple example of iterating over a shapes line segments and printing out the result.

```
public void printShapeSegments(Shape shape) {
    PathIterator it = shape.getPathIterator(new AffineTransform());

    double [] coords = new double[6];
    int currSegment = -1;
    while(!it.isDone()) {
        currSegment = it.currentSegment(coords);
        if(currSegment == PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE) {
            System.out.println("Close");
        } else if(currSegment == PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO) {
            System.out.println("Cubic");
        } else if(currSegment == PathIterator.SEG_LINETO) {
            System.out.println("Line");
        } else if(currSegment == PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO) {
            System.out.println("Move");
        } else if(currSegment == PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO) {
            System.out.println("Quad");
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(coords));
        it.next();
    }
}
```

In your code you could use this like `printShapeSegments(gv.getOutline())`